# Having trouble passing info into an array, in a separate class

Tags: c#, arrays

****Second edit****
Have the error handling figured out. But have a new issue with the output. All of the indexes of the array come out to zero no matter what is input. The only index that sticks is the last one. For example:
The number of hours of study that you did during the week are as follows:
Sunday: 0
Monday:0
Tuesday: 0
Wednesday: 0
Thursday: 0
Friday: 0
Saturday: (whatever the last number was that the user typed in... This is the only index that gets saved)

*I have a lot of trouble with parameters and methods. I don't understand what is supposed to go where. It feels so foreign to me. Anyway, this IS a homework assignment but its a super small piece. I'm hoping I can get some guidance and not get downvoted as I have in the past ...
I am getting a 'NullReferenceException" when EnterHours is called.*

```
public class StudentUI
{
    int myHours;
    private string[] days = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
    public StudentUI()
    {
    }

    public void MainMethod()
    {
        Student my = new Student();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name:\t ");
        my.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your student ID number:\t ");
        my.ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        FillHours(my);
        this.DisplayData(my);
        this.DisplayAverage(my);
    }

    public void FillHours(Student my)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.days.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the number of hours that you studied ITDEV-115 on {0}:\t ", this.days[i]);
            myHours = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            my.EnterHours(i, myHours);
        }
    }

public void DisplayAverage(Student my)
        {
            Console.Write("\n\nThe average number of hours studied per day was {0:N2}", my.CalculateAverage());

    }

    public void DisplayData(Student my)
    {
        double[] numHours = new double[this.days.Length];
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nName: {0}", my.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", my.ID);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nThe number of hours of study that you did during the week are as follows:");
        numHours = my.GetNumHours();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.days.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\t{0}:", this.days[i]);
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0:N2}", numHours[i]);
        }
    }
}

public class Student
{
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private double[] hours;

    public void EnterHours(int index, int myHours)
    {
        hours[index] = myHours;
    }

 public double[] GetNumHours()
        {
            return this.hours;
        }

public double CalculateAverage()
        {
            double num = 0;
            foreach (double number in this.hours)
            {
                num += number;
            }
            return (num / ((double)this.hours.Length));

        }
}
```

Comment: You do not show the full code. In particular you do not show where identifier `hours` is declared.

Comment: How do you get a NullReferenceException when this code doesn’t even compile considering your class declarations are invalid?

Comment: I'll post more of the code... thought I included all I needed.

Comment: I guess you must convert myHours to Double, not Int, in the Parse(Readline).

Comment: @MichaelM do you set a value to Student.hours? As it shows in your example its not initialized (and therefor NULL). You'll need to initialize it first.

Answer (score 1):

The instance field `private double[] hours;` is initially `null`, and you cannot set an entry of it in that case.

You need to create an actual array object.

*Somewhere* you must do `hours = new double[length]` where `length` is the length of the new array you want to create.

Comment: I Added: hours = new double[7] above hours[index] = myHours;
in the FillHours Method. It no longer gives me an error, but it keep overwriting the variable. So every input is reset to zero until the last day (Saturday). That is the only statement that actually stores the variable from user input.

Comment: @MichaelM Yes. Can you figure where else you could put the `hours = new double[7]` so that it will run only once per student?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
class StudentUI{

 int myHours;

 private string[] days = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
 "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };

 public StudentUI()
 { }

 public void MainMethod(){

   Student my = new Student(days.length);
   Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name:\t ");
   my.Name = Console.ReadLine();

   Console.WriteLine("Please enter your student ID number:\t ");
   my.ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    FillHours(my);
    this.DisplayData(my);
    this.DisplayAverage(my);
}

public void FillHours(Student my){

    for (int i = 0; i < this.days.Length; i++){

        Console.Write("Enter the number of hours that you studied ITDEV-115 on {0}:\t ", this.days[i]);
        myHours = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        my.EnterHours(i, myHours);
    }

}

class Student{

private int id;
private string name;
private double[] hours;

public student(int size)
{
hours = new double[size];
}
public void EnterHours(int index, int myHours)
    {
        hours[index] = myHours;

}
```

Arrays are of fixed length so you need to define the size of it before assigning any value. If you look at the constructor of Student class i have passed the length of days which is being used as the size of the array.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Ugh. That made sense when I read it. But after making those changes it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I converted from an array to a list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class StudentUI {
  int myHours;

  private string[] days = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
     "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };

  public StudentUI() { }

  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Student my = new Student();
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name:\t ");
    my.Name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your student ID number:\t ");
    my.ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    var StudentUI = new StudentUI();
    StudentUI.FillHours(my);
    // DisplayData(my);
    // DisplayAverage(my);
  }


    public void FillHours(Student my) {

      for (int i = 0; i < this.days.Length; i++) {

          Console.Write("Enter the number of hours that you studied ITDEV-115 on {0}:\t ", this.days[i]);
          myHours = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
          my.EnterHours(i, myHours);
      }
    }


}

public class Student {
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    private List<int> Hours = new List<int>();

    public void EnterHours(int index, int myHours) {
      Hours.Add(myHours);
    }
}
```